# AttributeError: Cannot use remove() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use songs.Playlist_Activity's Manager instead

Tags: python, django

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on figuring out how to remove an item in the manytomanyfield below but it doesn't seem to work and I am getting an attribute error. The remove method works totally fine without the intermediary model.

models.py

```
   class Song (models.Model):
        author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
        timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
        songname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
        tags = TaggableManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.songname

    class Playlist (models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
        song = models.ManyToManyField(Song, through='Playlist_Activity')


    class Playlist_Activity(models.Model):
        song= models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        playlist= models.ForeignKey(Playlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('timestamp',)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def Playlist_Remove(request, id, P_id):
    p = Playlist.objects.get(id=P_id)
    s = p.song.get(id=id)    
    p.song.remove(s)
    return redirect('account')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the intermediary instance:

```py
p = Playlist.objects.get(id=P_id)
s = Song.objects.get(id=id)
Playlist_Activity.objects.get(song=s, playlist=p).delete()
```

Comment: Now it shows: AttributeError: 'Playlist_Activity' object has no attribute 'remove'.

Comment: Try with `delete` instead of `remove`